# Studio: Gradle project sync failed.

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I tried some solutions but none of them helped.

I can't compile anything because of gradle's error:

Error:C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.8\native\jna\win32-amd64\jnidispatch.dll (System can't find this path)

In Settings I tried to check "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)" but it comes back to "Use local gradle distribution" with path C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.8

I downloaded gradle 2.8 from the official site but there's no "native" directory.

I updated everything with SDK and restart Studio but it also didn't help.

Android Studio 1.5.1, it's the same with all projects, even the new ones.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when switch to another computer. It's because project is keeping the reference to another computer paths.

For fix it i did:

I deleted the `.idea` folder from the project, like the highlight from image bellow.
Then you have to remove the project from android studio and open it again.

[image]

Comment: it's the same with even new projects, but I tried it and it didn't help, it's the same problem with gradle location. "Unlinked Gradle project?" @diogojme it's stille the same log "Error:C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.8\native\jna\win32-amd64\jnidispatch.dll (System cant find this path"

Comment: @krzk What version is in the `classpath` from your top-level `build gradle`?